# UTF-8 and ISO-8859-15 in Oracle Database

Tags: java, database, oracle, character-encoding, h2

I have:

1) Oracle database 1, where

```
SELECT * FROM v$nls_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

gives

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET                                                 
WE8ISO8859P15                                                             

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET                                           
AL16UTF16
```

2) Oracle database 2, where

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET                                                 
AL32UTF8                                                        

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET                                           
AL16UTF16
```

3) H2 database 3

So, I have copied some CLOBs from DB1 to DB2 using sqlloader. Then I've copied them to DB3 from DB2 using PreparedStatement.

And then i read them like

```
private String parseCLOB(Object t) {
    if (t instanceof oracle.sql.CLOB|| t instanceof org.h2.jdbc.JdbcClob) {
        InputStream i = t.getAsciiStream();
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(i, w, "UTF-8");
        t = w.toString();
    }
    return t
}
```

It has broken symbols for DB2, works fine for DB3. But if I substitute "ISO-8859-15", it works fine for DB2 and breaks for DB3.

What should I do to have both databases working?